# How to insert/inject an XML file into an other XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

For a student project, I need to inject an XML file into an other one using a python script. I don't really know how to do, I tried the xml.etree python module, but I didn't succeed. This  is my problem :

## file1.xml

```xml
<project>

   ...

   <publish>
      <a> Stuff </a>
   </publish>

   ...

</project>
```

## file2.xml

```xml
<b> Other stuff </b>
```

For the result, I want need to inject the file2.xml into the file1.xml at this exact position :

## file1.xml

```xml
<project>

   ...

   <publish>
      <a> Stuff </a>
      <b> Other stuff </b>  <----- Here
   </publish>

   ...

</project>
```

How can I do ?
Thank you for your time

Comment: always show your code and result which you get.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the specific contents of file1.xml.  If `</publish>` only occurs once, you don't need xml specific handling at all.

Open file1.xml for reading.

Open a new file for writing.

Loop over each line in file1.xml.

If the current line is `</publish>`, write your extra line to the new file.

Write the current line to the new file.

After all lines are written, rename file1.xml to file1.xml.bak and rename the new file to file1.xml.

```
with open('file1.xml') as file1, open('newfile.xml', 'w') as file2:
    for line in file1:
        if line == '   </publish>\n':
            file2.write('      <b> Other stuff </b>\n')
        file2.write(line)
os.rename('file1.xml', 'file1.xml.bak')
os.rename('newfile.xml', 'file1.xml)
```